# Using Ericsson Bowser to create hybrid mobile app for Webrtc

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webrtc, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to create a mobile application (that runs both on iOS and Android), but as far as I know this is currently not possible using hybrid app frameworks such as Cordova/Phonegap since iOS does not support WebRTC.

I wonder if it is possible to use Ericsson Bowser Browser (or any other browser that supports WebRTC on both platforms) to wrap my html app to achieve a hybrid app with WebRTC support for both platforms. Could anyone please guide me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking mostly about iOS, but I think you also need to ask whether Cordova can wrap Android WebRTC.  At least as recently as the end of 2014, the Android browser supported WebRTC, but the Android WebView did not.

According to this page
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

WebRTC is in WebView v36.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes I am asking mostly about iOS as there are plugins for Cordova to do this on Android, in addition to this Intel crosswalk offers this on Android but there are not many options on iOS. Ericsson Bowser browser works on both iOS and Android and supports WebRTC, it would be possible to get WebRTC support on both Android and iOS if the app is wrapped using Bowser just like crosswalk does this using Chromium and works with cordova but I need guidance to achieve this if this is even possible